# JQuery - Switch case depending on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, html, switch-statement, checkbox

I'm a designer trying to learn Jquery and I'm having a problem with a current project. I need to be able to click a checkbox which in turn reveals a div. For each checkbox clicked a different div must be generated. I thought a switch function would do the trick but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement it. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $(':checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
            switch(this.id) {

                    case "test1";
                    var newDiv = $('<div><p>it worked!!</p></div>');

            break;

            case "test2";
                    var newDiv = $('<div><p>it worked again!!</p></div>');

            break;

            default;
            }
            newDiv.insertAfter($(this));

            $(this).after(newDiv);
        } else {
            $(this).next().filter('div').remove();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much wrong is so little...

First problem is:

```
switch(this.id)
```

Which should be:

```
switch($(this).attr('id')) // Need to wrap in jQuery object
```

Also, your switch statement is wrong. Notice the `:` after `case` and not `;` as you have.

```
switch(n) {
    case 1:
        // Something
        break;
    case 2:
        // Something
        break;
    default:
        // Something
}
```

You need to declare `newDiv` outside the switch statement to access it later.
Then, these one after another makes no sense, they do the same thing

```
newDiv.insertAfter($(this)); // Keep this one
$(this).after(newDiv);
```

And, you have an extra `"` in your html, which was probably put by mistake...

```
<div">
```

Finally, you're mixing double quotes and single quotes which will give you headaches later on. I suggest you choose one or the other.

Comment: Thank you very much elclanrs, I had to wrap my head around your anser but it finally sunk in!! I appreciate your help very much!!

Answer (score 1):

why not just set up click functions for those specific ids?

```
$("#test1").click(function(){  $("your div1").show(); });
$("#test2").click(function(){  $("your div1").show(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
    <span style="display:none;"><div><p>it worked!</p></div></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
    <span style="display:none;"><div><p>it worked again!</p></div></span>
</div>
$(function () {
 $(':checkbox').click(function () {
  if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
   $(this).after($(this).next('span'));
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="div1" />
</div>

<div data-id='div1' style='display:none;'><p>it worked!</p></div>
<div data-id='div2' style='display:none;'><p>it worked again!</p></div>


$(function () {
  $(':checkbox').click(function () {
    var $box = $(this);    
    $("div[data-id='"+$box.attr('id')+"']").show();
  });
});
```